# How do you install gems from Gemfile.lock file?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, github

I am trying to run an app taken off Github.

I have run `bundle install` to install required gems from the `Gemfile`. However when running the app, an error message tells me the gems installed are the wrong version.

On inspecting the `Gemfile.lock` I note that the versions are older than the gems installed. (i.e. I have newer versions of gems installed and the application requires older gems.)

**Is there a quick way to install all the gems as per the versions described in the Gemfile.lock file? Alternatively is there a method to ignore that file?**

Gemfile:

```
   source 'http://rubygems.org'
   gem 'rails', "3.0.9"
   gem "sass"
   ..
```

Gemfile.lock:

```
 sass (3.1.1)
 ..
```

In the above example, even though sass is installed the app specially requires version 3.1.1.

Comment: Bundler should always install the versions in the `Gemfile.lock` file, that is it's purpose. Do you have never versions of those gems installed on your system?

Comment: I have newer gems installed than as specified by the app. When I run a bundle install the latest available gem version is installed.

Comment: Just delete the lock file and do bundle again.

Comment: As @Emrah said, if the project's gemfile is well written, it's supposed to declare the required gems versions. Therefore you should simply delete the gemfile.lock and run bundler and it should work. BTW, what project is it?

Comment: Deleting `Gemfile.lock` is actually not the best idea as it might result in an unintended and unsupported update of gem versions, especially with older apps where the gem versions have been loosely defined and will not survive a major version update.

Answer (score 13):

try this ..

```
bundle install --deployment
```

With above deployment option, bundle then reads from Gemfile.lock.

What's more, the gems are installed to **directory vendor/bundle**, with the bundle directory being **auto created**.

Also, new directory `.bundle` is created directly under the rails root directory, and has a file named config, whose content is as follows ...

```
BUNDLE_FROZEN: '1'
BUNDLE_PATH: vendor/bundle
BUNDLE_DISABLE_SHARED_GEMS: '1'
```

Hope the above works for you.

Answer (score 12):

With a valid `Gemfile.lock` file, `bundle install` alone should be sufficient, unless some particular gem version has been yanked. In that case you would need to look for an alternative gem version that is still currently available (usually `bundle update name_of_yanked_gem` would suffice).

About the `sass 3.1.1`, it is not so much that the application requires that particular version, but rather, that was likely the newest version available when the `Gemfile.lock` was last generated/updated given the overall version constraints as specified in `Gemfile`. As you have listed, there is no version range specified for `sass` itself, but other gems may impose further constraints if they have `sass` as a dependency.

Outright ignoring `Gemfile.lock` is not a good idea as under normal circumstances it will be specifying the gem versions that were last known to be still usable with the application.

Comment: Are you sure that bundle install is sufficient? For example, what if multiple versions of the same gem are installed (as is often the case)? I thought that's what `bundler execute` was for.

Comment: Regardless, if the `Gemfile.lock` has been generated, it will only contain one version for each specified gem after resolving the overall constraints. `bundle install` is for install, and `bundle exec` is for execution.

Comment: Ah ok, I think you're answering the asker's original question of "how do I install gems". I'm answering what I think his real problem is.

Answer (score 7):

Make sure you're running the web server with `bundle execute rails server`

Comment: +1 on this one, you need to run the server from bundler so that it utilizes the right gems.

Comment: this not `bundle exec rails server` but `bundle exec rails server`