# How to force Rails to install gems from Gemfile.lock?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubymine

Rails keep asking to install gems from Gemfile.lock.
I am using Rubymine on Windows 10.

I think the problem is similar with this one.
[How do you install gems from Gemfile.lock file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12215628/how-do-you-install-gems-from-gemfile-lock-file)

but no solution work.

error example:
no actionview in gemfile.
but there is actionview (5.1.6) in gemfile.lock.

```
Could not find actionview-5.1.6 in any of the sources
Run `bundle install` to install missing gems.
```

running `bundle install` produces this:

```
    Resolving dependencies.......
    Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "ruby ":
      In Gemfile:
    ruby 

    pg (= 0.20.0) was resolved to 0.20.0, which depends on
      ruby  (< 2.5) x64-mingw32

    fog (= 1.42) was resolved to 1.42.0, which depends on
      fog-ovirt was resolved to 1.2.0, which depends on
        rbovirt (~> 0.1.5) was resolved to 0.1.7, which depends on
          rest-client (> 1.7.0) was resolved to 2.0.2, which depends on
            ruby  (>= 2.0.0) x64-mingw32

    sqlite3 (= 1.3.13) was resolved to 1.3.13, which depends on
      ruby  (>= 1.8.7) x64-mingw32

Could not find gem 'ruby  (< 2.5)', which is required by gem 'pg (= 0.20.0)', in
any of the relevant sources:
  the local ruby installation

Process finished with exit code 6
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to install `ruby < 2.5` / `ruby >= 2.0.0` and write that version in `Gemfile` and/or in `.ruby-version`.

After that bundler will install all gems using `bundle` command.

> no actionview in gemfile. but there is actionview (5.1.6) in gemfile.lock

It's usual practice. There are dependent gems in `Gemfile.lock`

Comment: the installed ruby is already `ruby 2.5.5p157`.

Adding `gem "ruby",                    "2.5.5"` in gemfile gives me `Could not find gem 'ruby (= 2.5.5)' in any of the gem sources listed in your
Gemfile.`

Comment: No. You need to install ruby < 2.5. As you see 2.5.5 > 2.5. And that's not gem. It's Ruby. Which way did you install  `2.5.5`?

Comment: I use Ruby+Devkit 2.5.5-1 (x64) from https://rubyinstaller.org/downloads/.

now I have installed ruby 2.2.6. still the same problem.

Comment: how to write ruby version in gemfile btw?

Comment: Write in Gemfile `ruby '2.2.6'`